# Why the second div moves to another line even if both of them are set to display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm a bit afraid of using floats as I didn't yet understand clearing the floats and all the hacks that are on the internet in regard to that activity so I've used display:inline-block to place two divs in inline fashion. Their container has a

```
width:auto;
max-width:900px;
```

and each of the divs has

```
display:inline-block;
width: 450px;
```

Now no matter what I do the second div always breaks to another line right below the first div.

Here's the code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgtFd

I have already modified the width of the two divs like for example

```
width:440px;
```

but it didn't help. Still the second div is slightly 'off place'. That's weird cause I was making a website and using pretty much the same approach for my header like in this project. Please help me determine the problem.

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The widths are too wide.

Bump the nav down to about 446px, and they come back in line.

Why 444px instead of 450px?  Two reasons:

1. Your border is taking 2px.
2. There is whitespace between the `<div>` tags in your markup, which is reflected in the rendering.  If you would like it to be able to make it 450px, put the closing div tag and the next opening div tag immediately adjacent, like so: `</div><div id="nav">`

If you want to be able to keep the border, and set the width to 450px, then you should check out `box-sizing`, and utilize `box-sizing: border-box;`.

**Edit:**
To address your vertical alignment issues, you need to apply `vertical-align: top;` to the div elements (the nav and logo divs).

And, the `ul` isn't centered because when you apply `display:block` to it, it fills the full width.  So you could either make the *contents* of the div centered with `text-align: center` on the `ul`, or you could make the `ul` `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Even when I make the second div's width down to 440px for example, it goes on the right side indeed but is moved a bit down like if there would be a margin-top on the second div : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yktrB . Border was there only to visualize the space that each of the elements take. Also, why the ul isn't centered inside the nav container when I've added the display:block and margin: 0 auto; to the ul ?

Comment: Anyone willing to help ? :)

Comment: @Danny_Student - I've updated the answer to address your comments.

Comment: Thank you Cale ! I'm sorry to bother again but do I need to set a wrapper of a table that would surround these two elements when I'm using a parameter and value of 

    vertical-align: top